# file permission for website root dirr

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

I have set up a new site on Ubuntu 13.04 with Apache2.  The virtual host is set up and working fine.

I am getting an error in my Wordpress migration that says the root directory is not writeable by Php.  I am wondering what should the permissions on my sites root folder be to provide enough access for day to day needs but still be secure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Script to Configure Proper WordPress Permissions](http://www.conigliaro.org/2010/05/06/script-to-configure-proper-wordpress-permissions/) will be useful in your case.

Update1: If you looking for more general solution to setup your virtual hosts from template consider control panels like http://www.virtualmin.com/demo

The Virtualmin automatically will setup group for domain, virtual host and file permissions on root folder. 
When you finish with development stage, you can backup and migrate a domain with ease to production server.

Comment: Thanks that does help but can those settings be extrapolated as best practice in general for site root directories or just for ones that involve Wordpress?  That is really what I want to know.

Comment: You are welcome. Can you provide some information what is your target environment - development or production, virtual machine or shared hosting, etc.

Comment: This particular migration was to the development server which is a virtual machine (Rackspace cloud server) but I will be the one putting it live as well so both answers would be great